# Get last document from index in Elasticsearch

Tags: go, elasticsearch

I'm playing around the package github.com/olivere/elastic; all works fine, but I've a question: is it possible to get the last N inserted documents?
The From statement has 0 as default starting point for the Search action and I didn't understand if is possible to omit it in search.

Comment: Hi Gianluca, this package is deprecated. If you are just staring maybe switch to the newest version.

Comment: Hi Paulo! I use it because it seemed simple and working, but I didn't know about newest version. Can you suggest me anything? Thanks in advance

Comment: https://github.com/elastic/go-elasticsearch this is the newer version with official support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Tldr;

Although I am not aware of a feature in elasticsearch api to retrieve the latest inserted documents.

There is a way to achieve something alike if you store the ingest time of the documents.

Then you can sort on the ingest time, and retrieve the top N documents.